# Why "module 'google.cloud.bigquery' has no attribute 'format_options'"?

Tags: google-bigquery, pybigquery

I use bigquery fine in my code, but when I try to run this:

```
parquet_options = bigquery.format_options.ParquetOptions()
```

there is an exception:

> AttributeError("module 'google.cloud.bigquery' has no attribute
> 'format_options'")

https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigquery/latest/format_options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Issue can be resolved by upgrading the `gapic-generator`  and `google-cloud-bigquery` module. Can you try the below command:

```
pip3 install --upgrade gapic-generator 

pip3  install –upgrade google-cloud-bigquery
```

For more information you can refer to these [link1](https://pypi.org/project/gapic-generator/) and [link2](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-bigquery/)